# How to drag UIImageView using touches method

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to drag a `UIImageView` around the screen by touching the screen. But I want to be able to do a constant movement of the Sprite, currently my code only moves the sprite to the location of my touch and if I hold on touch on screen for some amount of time and then move, the sprite will follow. However I don't want to "have" to touch the `UIImageView` to activate the movement, I want to touch anywhere on the screen and have a movement response from that `UIImageView`, from its current location.

Here is my code.

```
var location = CGPoint()

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        ImageView.center = location}

}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Thank you for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simpler implementation. Just remember the last location of the touch and compute the difference, and use the difference to set the new location of the image.

```
var lastLocation = CGPoint()
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        self.lastLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    }
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        self.imageView.center = CGPoint(x: (location.x - self.lastLocation.x) + self.imageView.center.x, y: (location.y - self.lastLocation.y) + self.imageView.center.y)
        lastLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which i have write for `UIImageView`. In place of img you need to use you `sprite` object.

you need to create 3 global variable.

```
var offset: CGPoint
var isHold: Bool
var timerToCheckHold: NSTimer
```

use the touched method.

```
func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    var location: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view!)
    var imgCenter: CGPoint = img.center
    offset = CGPointMake(img.center.x - location.x, imgCenter.y - location.y)
    timerToCheckHold = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "timerToUpdateHold", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if timerToCheckHold != nil && timerToCheckHold.isValid() {
        timerToCheckHold.invalidate()
    }
    if isHold {
        var touch: UITouch = touches.first!
        var location: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view!)
        var newcenter: CGPoint = CGPointMake(offset.x + location.x, offset.y + location.y)
        img.center = newcenter
    }
}

func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if timerToCheckHold != nil && timerToCheckHold.isValid() {
        timerToCheckHold.invalidate()
    }
    isHold = false
}
```

Also you need to implement the timer method

```
func timerToUpdateHold() {
    isHold = true
}
```

Comment: it says invalid redeclaration of 'timerToCheckHold()'

Comment: I have updated the question. Change method name from timerToCheckHold() to timerToUpdateHold(). Please check now