# How to move UIImageView using drag event

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I would like to ask you about moving UIImageView.

Let’s imagine that an UIImageView is at location **X1**. If I want to move imv to location **X2** using **drag event**, How can I implement it?

Please give me advice.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drag UIImageView using touches method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008670/how-to-drag-uiimageview-using-touches-method)

Comment: It's similar, but those code is outdated, so it won'k work. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refered to [How to drag UIImageView using touches method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008670/how-to-drag-uiimageview-using-touches-method)

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView!
    var imgMarker:UIImage?
    var location = CGPoint()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        imgMarker = UIImage(named: "marker.png")
        imgView.image = imgMarker
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
        if let touch = touches.first {
            location = touch.location(in: self.view)
        imgView.center = location

        }
    }


}
```